# compact slice notation in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, slice

Is there a compact version of writing the following in Python 3:

```
print(columns[1],columns[8],columns[9])
```

Something like:

> print(columns[1,8,9])

To get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.__getitem__` doesn't support any sort of "selection" syntax, though you can use `operator.itemgetter` to achieve something similar:

```
from operator import itemgetter

print(itemgetter(1,8,9)(columns))
```

That said, a class could *define* `__getitem__` to support something similar. For example,

```
import operator


class ProjectionList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, tuple):
            return operator.itemgetter(*index)(self)
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(index)
```

Then

```
>>> z = ProjectionList([1,2,3])
>>> z[0]
1
>>> z[0,2]
(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(*itemgetter(1, 8, 9)(columns))
```

Comment: What does ' * ' do? How it's different than print(itemgetter(1,8,9)(columns)).